# Is Heroku's free plan fine for test tasks/pet-projects?

Tags: heroku

I can't see an email of their support to write to with that problem and as I think there is community of Heroku users here.
Is usage of free Heroku plan legit for deploying test tasks and pet projects e.g. for portfolio?

Comment: I already have 3 personal apps (apps, not just sites) on Heroku for myself, on free-tier. I say apps because it offers free add-ons, in my case I have ClearDB, so it offers free limited MySql database. A drawback is that you can't store files. You can upload, but after a while they get removed (more about that [here](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted))

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to use the Free plan for your personal development, experimenting but potentially production usage if you really want.
When working with free Dyno you have few limitations:

1. max number of free hours
2. Dyno goes to sleep after some inactivity time
3. no metrics
4. etc.. see [Dynos comparison](https://www.heroku.com/dynos)